# Firebase cannnot be initialized on localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can not initialize my Firebase database object in my localhost.
Can any body tell me what is wrong? As these are simple steps I am following from tutorial.

Below is my  script. I debug to find:

```
TypeError: database.set is not a function. help needed
```

---

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "*******CNyNrpH0vMVHnfJj44DhT4",
    authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://*******.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "******.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "*****433543"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


function function_1() {
  var database = firebase.database.ref();
   database.set("Text").value("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to see if you split the code into separate lines:

```
var promise = database.set("Text"); // this works
promise.value("hello world"); // "promise.value is not a function"
```

The first line works without problems now. But the second line give:

> promise.value is not a function

This error makes sense, because there is no function called `value` on the promise that `set()` returns.

Here a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/masuxab/edit?js,console). If you want to check the result, see this [REST GET](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/39815730.json).

If you're still having problems, can you set up a similar jsbin that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Another thing: the OP's code includes `firebase.database.ref()` which should be `firebase.database().ref()` - as in this answer's jsbin.

Comment: **That** explains the error message. I completely missed that. You might want to post it as a separate answer, since it is a better answer to the actual problem than mine.

Comment: Some How I am able to solve this issue.  I didn't Initialized firebase from Terminal to host it on my PC.  Although I am new to Firebase and was working behind proxy. Everything hassled up. Thanks much :)